# JS - Submit email and email another

Tags: javascript, input, mailto

I'm trying to allow customers to submit their email which will be emailed to another address onclick. This is what I have so far...

```
<input type="email" id="enteremail" href="#" style="height:42px; width:235px; font-size:12pt; border:0px; padding-left:10px" placeholder="Enter email..."  />
```

The button includes this code...

```
src="button.jpg" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="javascript:submitnewsletter()"
```

The JS...

```
function submitnewsletter()
{
    $("enteremail").attr('href',"mailto:my@myemail.com");
    document.getElementById('enteremail').value = "Thank you"
});
```

After submission, I wish for the input field to display 'Thank you'. I just can't seem to get this to work. Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `$("enteremail").attr('href',"mailto:my@myemail.com");` is a problem for two reasons. 1, the input element has no `href` attribute and 2, if you're using jQuery you should target the element as `$("#enteremail")`. That being said, I still don't follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: put a semicolon after "Thank you" this may be a simple syntax error

Comment: Best to refer to the example here as an example... http://jsfiddle.net/GVRXB/3/

Comment: The only code I can get to work so far is this... http://jsfiddle.net/5Ha3F/ 

The problem is I don't know how to incorporate an 'onclick' button instead of the text 'Click here to send feedback'.

Comment: I've managed to resolve this. Here's the js...

function submitnewsletter()
{
 emailsubmit = document.getElementById('enteremail').value
 if (emailsubmit == "") 
    {
 alert("Almost there. Please enter an email address.");
 return false;
   }
 window.location.href = "mailto:exports@championfreight.co.nz" + "?subject=" +emailsubmit;
 document.getElementById('enteremail').value = "Thank you"    
}

Answer (score 0):

When performing a submit the page reloads and all JavaScript resets as well. You would have to do a ajax request to post the submit data and wait for a response before printing.
Test out the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVRXB/14/)

If you wish to send more data with the form you would have to do a `$('#newsletter').serialize();` to get all the form data, and then append you custom email. I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish in the grand scheme of things, but hopefully this will lead you on the right path.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. Sorry - still new to this stuff.

http://jsfiddle.net/GVRXB/3/

Comment: Note that I referred to a #form, meaning an ID. So, your form should be of `<form id="form"...>`

Comment: Is there a ')' missing just after 'function(e)'? I tried adding one and it still didn't work.

Comment: @Evan Check my edit. I totally forgot about the need for ajax to accomplish this.

Comment: @stackoverflow ... I just don't understand. I've now been blocked from asking questions and I note -1 reputation for asking this question. I gave examples of my code... I expressed what I needed... I researched. Where did this go wrong?!